# Reshape long to wide on repeated rows

Tags: r, dataframe, transform, reshape, reshape2

I have a data frame `df` that looks like the following:

> ```
> Label              Info
> 1  0-22 Records    N/A 
> 2  0-22 Records    Poland
> 3  0-22 Records    N/A 
> 4  0-22 Records    active
> 5  0-22 Records    Hardcore 
> 6  0-22 Records    N/A 
> 7  0-22 Records    N/A
> 8  Nuclear Blast   "Oeschstr. 40 73072 Donzdorf"
> 9  Nuclear Blast   Germany
> 10 Nuclear Blast   +49 7162 9280-0 
> 11 Nuclear Blast   active
> 12 Nuclear Blast   Hardcore (early), Metal and subgenres 
> 13 Nuclear Blast   1987
> 14 Nuclear Blast   "Anstalt Records, Arctic Serenades, Cannibalised Serial Killer, Deathwish Office, Epica, Gore Records, Grind Syndicate Media,                                  Mind Control Records, Nuclear Blast America, Nuclear Blast Brasil,                                  Nuclear Blast Entertainment, Radiation Records, Revolution Entertainment"
> 15 Nuclear Blast   Yes
> ```

I would like to reshape to wide where `df` will look like:

```
  Label         Address    Country      Phone      Status       Genre      Year      Sub        Online
1 0-22 Records  N/A        Poland       N/A        active       Hardcore   N/A       N/A        N/A
2 Nuclear Blast "Oes.."    Germany      +49...
   .
   .
```

The number of repeated rows varies from 7 to 9 and I used `reshape` and `reshape2` with the key assigned to "Label" to no avail.

EDIT: `dput`:

```
structure(list(label = c("0-22 Records", "0-22 Records", "0-22 Records", 
 "0-22 Records", "0-22 Records", "0-22 Records", "0-22 Records", 
 "Nuclear Blast", "Nuclear Blast", "Nuclear Blast", "Nuclear Blast", 
 "Nuclear Blast", "Nuclear Blast", "Nuclear Blast", "Nuclear Blast", 
 "Metal Blade Records", "Metal Blade Records", "Metal Blade Records", 
 "Metal Blade Records", "Metal Blade Records"), info = c(" N/A ", 
 "Poland", " N/A ", "active", " Hardcore ", " N/A ", "N/A", " Oeschstr. 
 40\r\n73072 Donzdorf ", 
 "Germany", " +49 7162 9280-0 ", "active", " Hardcore (early), Metal and 
 subgenres ", " 1987 ", "\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tAnstalt 
 Records,\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tArctic Serenades,\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tCannibalised 
 Serial Killer,\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tDeathwish 
 Office,\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tEpica,\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tGore 
 Records,\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tGrind Syndicate Media,\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tMind 
 Control Records,\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tNuclear Blast 
 America,\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tNuclear Blast Brasil,\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tNuclear 
 Blast Entertainment,\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tRadiation 
 Records,\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tRevolution Entertainment\t\t\t\t\t      ", 
 "Yes", " 5737 Kanan Road #143\r\nAgoura Hills, California 91301 ", 
 "United States", " N/A ", "active", " Heavy Metal, Extreme Metal "
 )), .Names = c("label", "info"), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
 ), row.names = c(NA, -20L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x10200db78>)
```

Comment: The new column names (e.g., `Address`, `Country`, etc.) don't appear in the data. They need to be added as a new column in order to ensure that a given row's data ends up in the correct columns after reshaping. Is there a way to determine which of those new column names goes with which row(s) in the data?

Comment: It looks like `0-22 Records` lacks `Year` information. Look at the row count number. `0-22 Records` only has 7 rows, while `Nuclear Blast` has 8 rows.

Comment: Yes, I think that was the OP's point (see last line of the question). The solution would be straightforward if not for the variable number of rows for each level of `Label`.

Comment: Please add a sample of your data using `dput`. For example, to provide the first 15 rows, paste into your question the output of `dput(df[1:15,])`. (Although, given the idiosyncratic structure of the data frame, it would probably be better to provide a bigger sample in order to get a better idea of where the regularities and irregularities occur.)

Comment: If no other information for row 7 to 9, it would be difficult. For example, `0-22 Records    N/A` could mean `N/A` in  `Year`, `Sub`, or `Online`. I think it is necessary to provide some kinds of "labels" for this dataset.

Comment: The potential approaches depend on what you know about the data. For example, for `Label`s with only 7 (or 8) rows, are the same 2 (or 1) rows always missing or can they be different rows for different `Label`s?

Comment: @eipi10 different rows for different labels are missing, unfortunately. Also, in some cases, row 6 might be "sublabels", but in others, the same row corresponds with "parent labels".

Answer (score 1):

The new column names for the wide data frame (e.g., `Address`, `Country`, etc.) don't appear in `df`. We need to add a column to `df` that maps `info` to the correct column names for the wide data frame in order to ensure that a given row's data ends up in the correct columns after reshaping.

The challenge is that we need to find ways to exploit regularities in the data in order to figure out which values of `info` represent `Genre`, `Country`, `Year`, etc. Based on the data sample you've provided, here are some initial ideas. In the code below, the `case_when` statement is an attempt to map `info` to the new column names. Going in order, the statements within the `case_when` statement are trying to do the following:

- Find `Country` by identifying strings containing country names
- Find `Status` (assuming it can only be either "active" or "inactive")
- Find `Genre`. Here you'll need to cover more possibilities.
- Find `Year`. I've assumed any row with a four-digit number in the range 1950-2017 represents a year. Adjust as necessary.
- Find `Phone`. I've assumed it always starts with `+`, so you may need something more complex here.
- Find `Online` (assuming it can only be either "Yes" or "No", and that no row that would be mapped to a different column would ever contain only the word "Yes" or "No")
- Find `Sub`. You'll likely need a more complex strategy here. For now I've assumed rows that contain the words "Records" or "Entertainment" or that have three or more commas are `Sub` rows.
- If a row doesn't match any of the above statements, assume it's an address.

You'll need to play around with these and see what works in the context of your data.

```
library(stringr)
library(tidyverse)
library(countrycode)
data("countrycode_data")

df %>% 
  filter(!grepl("N/A", info)) %>% 
  mutate(info = str_trim(gsub("\r*\t*|\n*| {2,}", "", info)),
         NewCols = case_when(sapply(info, function(x) any(grepl(x, countrycode_data$country.name.en))) ~ "Country",  
                             grepl("active", info) ~ "Status",                                                         
                             grepl("hardcore|metal|rock|classical", info, ignore.case=TRUE) ~ "Genre",
                             info %in% 1950:2017 ~ "Year",
                             grepl("^\\+", info) ~ "Phone",
                             grepl("^Yes$|^No$", info) ~ "Online",
                             grepl("Records|Entertainment|,{3,}", info) ~ "Sub",
                             TRUE ~ "Address")) %>% 
  group_by(label) %>% 
  spread(NewCols, info)
```

Here's the output (where I've truncated the long value of `Sub` to save space):

```
                label                                            Address       Country                                 Genre Online           Phone Status            Sub  Year
                <chr>                                              <chr>         <chr>                                 <chr>  <chr>           <chr>  <chr>          <chr> <chr>
1        0-22 Records                                               <NA>        Poland                              Hardcore   <NA>            <NA> active             NA  <NA>
2 Metal Blade Records 5737 Kanan Road #143Agoura Hills, California 91301 United States            Heavy Metal, Extreme Metal   <NA>            <NA> active             NA  <NA>
3       Nuclear Blast                         Oeschstr. 4073072 Donzdorf       Germany Hardcore (early), Metal and subgenres    Yes +49 7162 9280-0 active  Anstalt Re...  1987
```

**Original answer (before data sample was available)**

If you had all nine rows for each `Label`, and the data type in each row is always in the same order for each `Label`, then one solution would be:

```
library(tidyverse)

df.wide = df %>% 
  group_by(Label) %>% 
  mutate(NewCols = rep(c("Address","Country","Phone","Status","Genre","Year","Sub","Online"), length(unique(Label)))) %>% 
  spread(NewCols, Info)
```

You can implement this in your real data for any level of `Label` that has 9 rows.

```
df.wide9 = df %>% 
  group_by(Label) %>% 
  filter(n()==9) %>% 
  mutate(NewCols = rep(c("Address","Country","Phone","Status","Genre","Year","Sub","Online"), length(unique(Label)))) %>% 
  spread(NewCols, Info)
```

For the levels of `Label` with 8 or 7 rows, if the missing rows always represent the same type of data, for example, say the address row is the one that's always missing for the 8-row levels of `Label`, then you could do (once again, assuming the data data types are in the same order for each `Label`):

```
df.wide8 = df %>% 
  group_by(Label) %>% 
  filter(n()==8) %>% 
  mutate(NewCols = rep(c("Country","Phone","Status","Genre","Year","Sub","Online"), length(unique(Label)))) %>% 
  spread(NewCols, Info)
```

Then you could put them together with `df.wide = bind_rows(df.wide8, df.wide9)`.

If you provide more information, we might be able to come up with a solution that works for your actual data.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately none of these work due to variations of `Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Column NewCols must be length 9 (the group size) or one, not 8` or `7`.